# Sql Server pivot command based on text giving null cells

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have a table in the following format

```
╔════════╦══════════════╦════════╦════════════╦══════════╦════════╦══════════╦══════════╗
║ Answer ║ QuestionText ║ type   ║ QuestionID ║ ResultID ║ Action ║ Username ║ SurveyID ║
╠════════╬══════════════╬════════╬════════════╬══════════╬════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║ FN 1   ║ First Name   ║ text   ║ 3467       ║ 2259     ║ 2259   ║ admin    ║ 308      ║
║ LN 1   ║ Last Name    ║ text   ║ 3468       ║ 2259     ║ 2259   ║ admin    ║ 308      ║
║ Male   ║ Gender       ║ radio  ║ 3466       ║ 2259     ║ 2259   ║ admin    ║ 308      ║
║ 12     ║ Age          ║ number ║ 3469       ║ 2259     ║ 2259   ║ admin    ║ 308      ║
║ FN 2   ║ First Name   ║ text   ║ 3467       ║ 2260     ║ 2260   ║ admin    ║ 308      ║
║ LN 2   ║ Last Name    ║ text   ║ 3468       ║ 2260     ║ 2260   ║ admin    ║ 308      ║
║ Female ║ Gender       ║ radio  ║ 3466       ║ 2260     ║ 2260   ║ admin    ║ 308      ║
║ 12     ║ Age          ║ number ║ 3469       ║ 2260     ║ 2260   ║ admin    ║ 308      ║
╚════════╩══════════════╩════════╩════════════╩══════════╩════════╩══════════╩══════════╝
```

I am trying pivot it using the following pivot query.

```
SELECT [ResultID],[Username],[Action],[First Name],[Last Name],[Gender],[Age] from 
            (
                select * 
                from #myTab
           ) as y
            pivot 
            (
                 max(Answer)
                for QuestionText in ([First Name],[Last Name],[Gender],[Age])
            ) as p
```

But I am getting the following table as the pivot result

```
╔══════════╦══════════╦════════╦════════════╦═══════════╦════════╦══════╗
║ ResultID ║ Username ║ Action ║ First Name ║ Last Name ║ Gender ║ Age  ║
╠══════════╬══════════╬════════╬════════════╬═══════════╬════════╬══════╣
║ 2259     ║ admin    ║ 2259   ║ NULL       ║ NULL      ║ NULL   ║ 12   ║
║ 2260     ║ admin    ║ 2260   ║ NULL       ║ NULL      ║ NULL   ║ 12   ║
║ 2259     ║ admin    ║ 2259   ║ NULL       ║ NULL      ║ Male   ║ NULL ║
║ 2260     ║ admin    ║ 2260   ║ NULL       ║ NULL      ║ Female ║ NULL ║
║ 2259     ║ admin    ║ 2259   ║ FN 1       ║ NULL      ║ NULL   ║ NULL ║
║ 2260     ║ admin    ║ 2260   ║ FN 2       ║ NULL      ║ NULL   ║ NULL ║
║ 2259     ║ admin    ║ 2259   ║ NULL       ║ LN 1      ║ NULL   ║ NULL ║
║ 2260     ║ admin    ║ 2260   ║ NULL       ║ LN 2      ║ NULL   ║ NULL ║
╚══════════╩══════════╩════════╩════════════╩═══════════╩════════╩══════╝
```

I am not sure why I am getting all these `NULL` values. It will be a big help if someone could tell me why this is happening , and the correct to way to get the following pivot output:

```
╔══════════╦══════════╦════════╦════════════╦═══════════╦════════╦══════╗
║ ResultID ║ Username ║ Action ║ First Name ║ Last Name ║ Gender ║ Age  ║
╠══════════╬══════════╬════════╬════════════╬═══════════╬════════╬══════╣
║ 2259     ║ admin    ║ 2259   ║ FN 1       ║ LN 1      ║ Male   ║ 12   ║
║ 2260     ║ admin    ║ 2260   ║ FN 2       ║ LN 2      ║ Female ║ 12   ║
╚══════════╩══════════╩════════╩════════════╩═══════════╩════════╩══════╝
```

[Source table in csv format](http://datahub.ae/Content/result.csv)

Comment: Ahhh, ASCII tables... :D

Comment: You need to select only the columns you need in the subquery.  I so prefer conditional aggregation to the `pivot` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior... you should use a GROUP BY with a aggregate function (like Max() or First() or string concatenation (maybe stuff?) depending on your requirements) to reduce the results to a single row per entity (defined by the key you group on)

Edit: Try;

```
SELECT 
[ResultID],
max([Username]) as Username,
max([Action]) as action,
max([First Name]) as FirstName,
max([Last Name]) as LastName,
max([Gender]) as gender,
max([Age]) as age from 
            (
                select * 
                from #myTab
           ) as y
            pivot 
            (
                 max(Answer)
                for QuestionText in ([First Name],[Last Name],[Gender],[Age])
            ) as p
GROUP BY 
    ResultId
```

Comment: I would love to know how. As I am fairly new to the sql server and pivot procedure. I do not possess the required vocabulary to search and find this in stackoverflow. If you can tell me how to apply the group by or can mark the question as duplicate. I will be thankful to you

Comment: Thank you, This works for me, and all the other answers

Comment: This is overkill.. your pivot will group everything not aggregated (*) then you group them again.  Just select the fields you want to see in your final result in your derived table

Comment: @JamieD77 But if you do that, then adding a new field to the table (which SHOULD be a non-breaking change) will break the query... Also if there are any duplicates, they will be duplicated in the results... I would not let that through a code review as it will be prone to break in future... and it is not a performance concern because SQL is clever enough to only do the second group if it needs too (to eliminate duplicates etc.). Also, what if he wants to show another field in the query anyway?

Comment: @Milney how does adding a field to a table break a query?  Only removing a field that you're selecting would break the query..  You can downvote my answer all you want, but it beats this query by a mile.

Answer (score 2):

Just limit the fields required to X-Axis, Y-Axis(n) and Value

```
Select [ResultID],[Username],[Action],[First Name],[Last Name],[Gender],[Age] 
 From (
        Select resultid
              ,Action 
              ,Username
              ,questiontext
              ,answer
        From  #Table21
    ) y
   pivot (max(Answer) for QuestionText in ([First Name],[Last Name],[Gender],[Age])) P
```

Comment: This still doesn't help, he still needs a group by to only get one row per resultid

Comment: This is brittle as table could change and then it would randomly stop working... also duplicate rows would still produce duplicates. This is lazy in my opinion and I wouldn't let past code review -  safer to aggregate

Comment: Thank you.I have tried this answer and it also works

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE #Table21
    ([Answer] varchar(6), [QuestionText] varchar(10), [type] varchar(6), [QuestionID] int, [ResultID] int, [Action] int, [Username] varchar(5), [SurveyID] int)
;

INSERT INTO #Table21
    ([Answer], [QuestionText], [type], [QuestionID], [ResultID], [Action], [Username], [SurveyID])
VALUES
    ('FN 1', 'First Name', 'text', 3467, 2259, 2259, 'admin', 308),
    ('LN 1', 'Last Name', 'text', 3468, 2259, 2259, 'admin', 308),
    ('Male', 'Gender', 'radio', 3466, 2259, 2259, 'admin', 308),
    ('12', 'Age', 'number', 3469, 2259, 2259, 'admin', 308),
    ('FN 2', 'First Name', 'text', 3467, 2260, 2260, 'admin', 308),
    ('LN 2', 'Last Name', 'text', 3468, 2260, 2260, 'admin', 308),
    ('Female', 'Gender', 'radio', 3466, 2260, 2260, 'admin', 308),
    ('12', 'Age', 'number', 3469, 2260, 2260, 'admin', 308)

with cte as
(
SELECT [ResultID],[Username],[Action],[First Name],[Last Name],[Gender],[Age] from 
            (
                select * 
                from #Table21
           ) as y
            pivot 
            (
                 max(Answer)
                for QuestionText in ([First Name],[Last Name],[Gender],[Age])
            ) as p
            )


SELECT   
     [ResultID],  
     max([Username]) AS [Username],  
     MAX([Action]) AS [Action],  
     MAX([First Name]) AS [First Name],  
     MAX([Last Name]) AS [Last Name]  ,
     MAX([Gender]) AS [Gender],
     MAX([Age]) AS [Age]
FROM CTE  
GROUP BY [ResultID];
```

output

```
ResultID    Username    Action  First Name  Last Name   Gender  Age
2259    admin   2259    FN 1    LN 1    Male    12
2260    admin   2260    FN 2    LN 2    Female  12
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use CASE expressions with Aggregates to basically PIVOT a result.  I use this regularly because if for some reason I want to add another aggregated column I can without having to do another PIVOT.  It's also faster in some cases.

```
SELECT 
    [ResultID],
    [UserName],
    [Action],
    MAX(CASE WHEN c.[QuestionText] = 'First Name' THEN [Answer] END) as [First Name],
    MAX(CASE WHEN c.[QuestionText] = 'Last Name' THEN [Answer] END) as [Last Name],
    MAX(CASE WHEN c.[QuestionText] = 'Gender' THEN [Answer] END) as [Gender],
    MAX(CASE WHEN c.[QuestionText] = 'Age' THEN [Answer] END) as [Age]
FROM 
    cte c
GROUP BY
    [ResultID],
    [UserName],
    [Action]
```

example:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT * FROM (
VALUES
    ('FN 1', 'First Name', 'text', 3467, 2259, 2259, 'admin', 308),
    ('LN 1', 'Last Name', 'text', 3468, 2259, 2259, 'admin', 308),
    ('Male', 'Gender', 'radio', 3466, 2259, 2259, 'admin', 308),
    ('12', 'Age', 'number', 3469, 2259, 2259, 'admin', 308),
    ('FN 2', 'First Name', 'text', 3467, 2260, 2260, 'admin', 308),
    ('LN 2', 'Last Name', 'text', 3468, 2260, 2260, 'admin', 308),
    ('Female', 'Gender', 'radio', 3466, 2260, 2260, 'admin', 308),
    ('12', 'Age', 'number', 3469, 2260, 2260, 'admin', 308)
) t([Answer],[QuestionText],[type],[QuestionID],[ResultID],[Action],[Username],[SurveyID]))

SELECT 
    [ResultID],
    [UserName],
    [Action],
    MAX(CASE WHEN c.[QuestionText] = 'First Name' THEN [Answer] END) as [First Name],
    MAX(CASE WHEN c.[QuestionText] = 'Last Name' THEN [Answer] END) as [Last Name],
    MAX(CASE WHEN c.[QuestionText] = 'Gender' THEN [Answer] END) as [Gender],
    MAX(CASE WHEN c.[QuestionText] = 'Age' THEN [Answer] END) as [Age]
FROM 
    cte c
GROUP BY
    [ResultID],
    [UserName],
    [Action]


ResultID    UserName Action      First Name Last Name Gender Age
----------- -------- ----------- ---------- --------- ------ ------
2259        admin    2259        FN 1       LN 1      Male   12
2260        admin    2260        FN 2       LN 2      Female 12
```